# Setting up 2 factor authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, authentication, iis-7

We are in the process of building a new website which we want to lock down to specific computers to only allow access, then once the pc is authenticated we will do our in built user authentication.

Also, when a pc is known, we dont really want anything on the pc which can be easily transfered (by the client) onto another pc in order to gain access to the website.

Please can anyone give us an idea on the best way to achieve this 'lock down', we dont really want to go down the AD route and have loads of extra user data to maintain.

Thanks in advance.
Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP and MAC addresses are trivial to spoof.  Without Trusted Computing, there is nothing you can really trust to authenticate a PC.  What you need to figure out is what can you do that gets you an acceptable level of trust.  Here's what we have done with our "locked" tokens:  They take  some info from the PC and hash them and send that hash to the auth server. Any requests for an OTP then needs to be accompanied by that hash. It's not perfect, but it also handles mutual https authentication, so it thwarts network-based MITM attacks too. If the token is stolen, the attacker must also know what info to spoof and spoof it. Again, it's not perfect, but better than nothing given the current state of PC security.  http://www.wikidsystems.com/downloads/token-clients and our sourceforge page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wikid-twofactor/

Answer (score 1):

specific computers on your network?

set some IP restrictions in IIS, this assumes your DHCP box is giving out static IPs.

The only way a user could "transfer" the authentication is to take their NIC with them, or clone its MAC address.

Comment: It wont be specific to our network, it will be machines outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Helicon Ape free](http://www.helicontech.com/download-ape.htm) and put [.htacces and .htpasswd files](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/htaccess-generator.shtml) in the root of the site you are trying to protect.