# IIS7 Restrict website access by MAC address?

Tags: authentication, iis-7, windows-server-2008, mac-address

Is it possible to restrict access to a website in IIS7 using MAC address rather than IP address?

We are wanting to restrict access to our website to only known PCs as mentioned here: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307362/setting-up-2-factor-authentication). These PCs will be external to our network, but because some users could be remote, we would rather do this on MAC address rather than IP address.

II7, Windows Server 2008, asp.net

Thankyou in advance

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bad idea because MAC addresses can easily be spoofed. If you need authentication from multiple unknown locations you should use passwords or certificates.

And of course, as mentioned in another answer, over the Internet the MAC adress is not visible, it would only be possible inside your own network.

Comment: We would be using this in the 2 factor authentication, this is part one and then the user authentication is part 2.

We only want 'Known' pcs to access the website, as we dont want this to be open to just anyone, or open to staff when they go home.

Comment: Even if it were possible, the staff at the computer could easily find out the mac address and set their home computer to the same one. The mac address is something you (and too many others) know, not something you are or something you have. It is not suitable for 2-factor authentication.

Comment: what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Use a token, or maybe a certificate (Altough I'm not sure if you can prevent users from exporting it and taking it with them).

Answer (score 3):

You can't restrict access by MAC address because MAC address is using only in local network to communicate devices and behind any router information about ARP table can't be recognited.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You'd have to have some kind of application installed on the client machine such as an ActiveX control to get that information.

Perhaps you should consider having the website setup like an intranet and setup a VPN for the remote viewers. Look at Logmein's Hamachi. It's a super simple VPN setup and free to try.

Comment: Installing an app on the client PC would not be a problem to be honest.

Comment: due to some browser limitations i wouldn't suggest this route.

Comment: @Jeremy, I'm a huge fan of Hamachi as well however the OP wanted the MAC address in the context of ASP.NET and IIS. My response regarding "browser limitations" was referring to an ActiveX control.

Comment: @used2could agreed. and it is really an odd question.

Answer (score 0):

The ISAPI extensions will not provide access to network layer information from the client end. This information has to be polled directly from the other end. Also MAC address is extremely unreliable as it can be spoofed more easily than an IP address can be.