# Accessing unique ID for a client machine

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webapi

Basically in our website,we are looking forward to Identify a client machine with a UniqueID forever.
The technologies we are currently using are .Net core,Angular and web API?
I know it is very difficult to identify from browser. However, would like to know is there any way around this?
Does progressive web app will help out?
Currently we are installing the certificate in each client machine and Identify with those serial no

Comment: [Does the answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47575385/7687666)