# How to get Client IP Address and MAC Address in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ip-address, mac-address

I am working on laravel project. I need to access client's IP Address and MAC Address those who access the website.

Is their any way to get both the Addresses.

I've used:

```
Request::ip();
```

I got the IP address of client. But how to get MAC address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309122/how-can-i-get-a-mac-address-from-an-http-request) is a good answer to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the MAC and the IP address of a connected client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Yes You Can Do it

> BY DEFAULT PHP HAS A BUILT IN FUNCTION THAT EXECUTES THE COMMAND LINE
>   COMMANDS

**shell_exec**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

**exec**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

So To get the mac address have written the function

```
 function getMAcAddressExec()
{
        return substr(exec('getmac'), 0, 17); 
}
echo getMAcAddressExec();


function getMAcAddressShellExec()
{
        return substr(shell_exec('getmac'), 159,20); 
}
echo getMAcAddressShellExec();
```

**EDITED**

add follwowing lines in `web.php` file in `routes` folder

```
Route::get('/getmacshellexec',function()
    {
        $shellexec = shell_exec('getmac'); 
        dd($shellexec);
    }
);

Route::get('/getmacexec',function()
    {
        $shellexec = exec('getmac'); 
        dd($shellexec);
    }
);
```

And Try the url

```
yourproject/getmacshellexec
```

AND

```
yourproject/getmacexec
```

And Kindly Comment Below of you get any any output

Comment: which platform you are working with linux or windows

Comment: are you trying it in the live web server

Answer (score 1):

**Server IP**
You can get the server IP address from $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].

**Server MAC address**
For the MAC address, you could parse the output of netstat -ie in Linux, or ipconfig /all in Windows.

**Client IP address**
You can get the client IP from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

**Client MAC address**
The client MAC address will not be available to you except in one special circumstance: if the client is on the same ethernet segment as the server.

So, if you are building some kind of LAN based system and your clients are on the same ethernet segment, then you could get the MAC address by parsing the output of arp -n (linux) or arp -a (windows).
**But what if the client isn't on a LAN?**

Well, you're out of luck unless you can have the client volunteer that information and transmit via other means.

Comment: Answer credits to [Paul Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420402/2336650)

Answer (score 0):

The `exec()` is a function that is used to run an external program in PHP. It returns the last line from the result of the command. To get the MAC address, pass the parameter `getmac` which returns the MAC address of the client. `getmac`is a CMD command to get the MAC address.

To get the **MAC address**, we use `exec()` function.

```
$macAddr = exec('getmac');
```

For getting the **IP address** we have to include use `Illuminate\Http\Request;` in the Controller and then add the code of the below pre tag. It will give the AP address of the network.

```
$ipAddr=\Request::ip();
```

Comment: does it run on mobile.?