# Is there diffrence to get MAC address PC and Cellphone?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to get MAC address in Laravel project.
my Laravel Framework is 6.18.8

I use below code and I could get MY PC's MAC address sucessfully 
However When I access this page by my cellphone I can't get MAC address. 
I looked Mysql database's table, the MAC column was empty. 
Could someone teach me right code please?

**THis is my current code**

```
 function getMAcAddressExec()
    {
            return substr(exec('getmac'), 0, 17); 
    }
```

Comment: Is your Laravel instance on your PC? Also, are you looking for the cell phone mac address or the server mac address?

Comment: This might help explain things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309122/how-can-i-get-a-mac-address-from-an-http-request

Comment: Dear @Jared Dunham. Yes It is. And I would like to get cell phone mac address. I read Mr. Eric Van Joshnon 's answer. Now I understand that. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Eric Van Joshnon. Thank you very much. I'm clear now. You help me alot. Thank you again.