# How to access client's MAC address in Restful web services

Tags: java, rest

I have a angular application, which is making a rest call as:

`http://localhost:8765/test/iptest`

And in my controller :

```
@GetMapping(value = "test/iptest")
public ResponseEntity<Object> doTest() {
    log.debug("Inside Test");
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Test success", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How do I access client's **IP** and **MAC address** using this request?

**EDIT:**
I was able to access Client's IP Address using **HttpServletRequest** as:

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

    @GetMapping(value = "test/iptest")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> doTest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.debug("IP Address is:"+request.getRemoteAddr());
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Test success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But I'm not able to access **MAC ADDRESS**

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to get the mac address.

Comment: I think this is not possible. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309432/3511168

Answer (score 3):

You can't - other than on the local LAN, remote MAC addresses are not exposed to your end point.   The MAC address in the Ethernet header of the packet received at the server will be that of the nearest router that was the last hop in the path.

Even on the local LAN you cannot get this information for an IP socket - looking up a local MAC address requires poking around in the OS's ARP tables.